# Fetching data from Yahoo weather API in dropdown and after click on city it show the weather of selected city

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, api

**DB Query** :

```
var query = new YQL('select * from weather.forecast where (location = '+req.params.locationNumber+')');
```

**Here is the HTML**:

```
<select ng-model="city" class="form-control" ng-options="city.location as city.cityName for city in cities" ng-init="city=''" data-ng-click="getWeather(city)">
                  <option value="">Select City</option>
                </select>
```

**Here is the Angular.js** :

```
    $scope.getWeather = function(data){
        if(data){       
            appService.get({url: 'weather', id: data}).$promise.then(function(data) { 
                $scope.weather = data.temp;
            }).catch(function(error){
                growl.addErrorMessage('oops something went wrong');
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? There isn't much here to go on...

Comment: I agree, what's the question?

Comment: I want to fetch data from Yahoo API. In this, I have manipulate cities in the dropdown and when click any city then it should show the whether of selected city.